# MS SQL Server comparing values with HEX

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Must have overlooked something here with this query that converts and compares vales in hex

```
select NAME, convert(varchar, convert(Varbinary(MAX), NAME),2), convert(varchar, convert(Varbinary(MAX), 'freddy'),2) from CUSTOMERS
```

works fine, but as you can see, value retrieved from database is padded with 00 blanks

```
freddy  660072006500640064007900    667265646479
```

wasn't expecting that... is there any way of dropping them..?

Oh, additional information, the 00 is provision for unicode characters, which is good, however I just want my hexed "freddy" to match my retrieved "freddy" in hex

Any guidance gratefully accepted, cheers

Sorted next day by adding an extra **convert(varchar(MAX), USRPWRD)** so this;

```
convert(varchar, convert(Varbinary(MAX), convert(varchar(MAX), USRPWRD)),2)
```

returns this

```
667265646479
```

wouldn't be so good if unicode characters were required in the field

ANOTHER DAY OR TWO LATER...

Now I've discovered that my SQL query only returns part of the hex. Here is the value of the email address in my database;

```
whatever.happened@rumplestiltzken.com
```

This is the email address converted to hex

```
77686174657665722E68617070656E65644072756D706C657374696C747A6B656E2E636F6D
```

This is the relevant part of my query

```
convert(varchar, convert(Varbinary(MAX), convert(varchar(MAX), USREMAIL)),2)
```

This is what it returns, which is exactly the first 30 chars of the full hex string above

```
77686174657665722E68617070656E
```

How do I get the full hex returned..? Help please!

SOLVED (needs (MAX) on the final vchar)

```
convert(varchar(MAX), convert(Varbinary(MAX), convert(varchar(MAX), USREMAIL)),2)
```

Comment: You're having a lot of trouble with datatypes. Never use `varchar` alone. Always use with a size designator. i.e. use `varchar(max)`, not `varchar`. What datatype is `USREMAIL`?

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid and you're right, I am having "fun & games" caused by me being the sales guy really and the developer left the building some time ago. Anyway, USREMAIL is nvarchar which is why I had to convert it to vchar before hexing it otherwise I got hex for a unicode string with all the 00 padding in it. Just don't understand why I only get a 30 character hex string back. SQL "convert" documentation mentions truncation, but I don't know what the size limits are... 30 it seems

Comment: 5 MINUTES LATER! Hey @Nick.McDermaid you're a genius, stupid here didn't immediately realise you were pointing out the final vchar didn't have a (MAX) on it, so now... it works..!

Comment: ha no genius..., just done a lot of debugging like this and know the traps. You should write up your results (now that you are flushed with success) for other players to find and accept it as an answer. Just be very particular about data types. There are a lot of unexpected internal rules applied when 'implicit casts' occur so it's best to be very exact about data types.